# Django Python Merge Some Data in Json

Tags: python, json

How to merge some data under a single JSON object. As you can see in JSON format below, I want to have (Company address & house address) under the same object (Address).

```
[
   {
      "full_data":[
         {
            "name":"James",
            "email":"James@yahoo.com",
            "phone":"1234567890",
            "address_type":"home"
            "address":"address"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "full_data":[
         {
            "name":"James",
            "email":"James@yahoo.com",
            "phone":"1234567890",
            "address_type":"company"
            "address":"address"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

My desired output will be to have the following format:

```
{
   "full_data":[
      {
         "name":"James",
         "email":"James@yahoo.com",
         "phone":"1234567890",
         "address":{
            "house_address":"address",
            "company_address":"address"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Update:

Here is the code for Views.py file:

```
class DataView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DataList.objects.all()

    serializer_class = DataSerializer
```

Here is the code for Serializers.py file:

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data_details = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = DataList
        fields = 'data_details'

    def get_data_details(self, obj):
        return [{
            'name': obj.name,
            'email': obj.email,
            'phone': obj.phone,
            'address_type': obj.address_type,
            'address': obj.address,
        }]
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a "json object". I mean: at runtime, what you have is either a json-formatted string or a python dict (or list of dicts etc - but most often a dict).

Answer (score 1):

We can do it in python like below

```py
l = [
   {
      "full_data":[
         {
            "name":"James",
            "email":"James@yahoo.com",
            "phone":"1234567890",
            "address_type":"home",
            "address":"address"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "full_data":[
         {
            "name":"James",
            "email":"James@yahoo.com",
            "phone":"1234567890",
            "address_type":"company",
            "address":"address"
         }
      ]
   }
]
d = {}
for i in l:
    type = i["full_data"][0].pop("address_type")
    address = i["full_data"][0].pop("address")
    if d.get("full_data"):
        d['full_data'][0].update(i['full_data'][0])
        d["full_data"][0]["address"][type+"_address"] = address
    else:
        d.update(i)
        d["full_data"][0]["address"] = {type+"_address": address}
print(d)
```

## Ouput

```py
{'full_data': [{'address': {'company_address': 'address',
    'home_address': 'address'},
   'email': 'James@yahoo.com',
   'name': 'James',
   'phone': '1234567890'}]}
```

Comment: Hi @Anjaneyulu, thanks for your answer. I have slightly changed the original JSON response and have included in the question post together with Views.py and Serializers.py files. May I know where do i need to put your code?

Comment: Thanks @Anjaneyulu. May I know where to put that code? Do I put in Views.py or Serializers.py file?

Comment: @Mack I didn't know that. Please accept the answer and give an upvote.